# Selenium IDE - Auto-calculation

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

I have a form, in which there are Weight and height fields. When I key-in values in these two fields, the value in the "BMI" field is auto-filled. This is working fine when I do it manually, but when using IDE, the value in the BMI is not filled.

Please give specific answers wrt Selenium IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write manually in the text box. Selenium IDE do not accept value form autoload drop down box

```
 pause |  1000
 type  |  id of text box |  value
```

or

```
pause      | 1000
Storeeval  | prompt("enter the value") | value
textbox    | id or xpath of textbox    | ${value}
```

Comment: @abhi - Please check above code and let me know it work for you or not

Answer (score 0):

Is putting delay in between help you out ?
driver.sendKeys ();
sleep(); (Thread Sleep from Java)

For IDE to wait use this 
    pause(); 
    target = 3000 (3 secs); 
    value = ;(empty)

Comment: That applies only for selenium webdriver

Comment: Can anyone please tell how to achieve this with Selenium IDE.

Comment: For IDE to wait use this pause(); target = 3000 (3 secs); value = empty